# code point and UTF-16 code units are the same thing?

Tags: javascript, unicode, character, translation, utf-16

Currently, I'm going to use Azure and GCP Translation API, both of which count the number of characters based on 'code point'.

At the same time, I'm trying to count the number of characters on my node.js server as well, before sending text to them. My way to count the number of characters is simple Javascript's `length` property, like this:

```
var originalText = 'hello 世界';
var textLen = originalText.length; //this is the right way to count the number of 'code point's?
// send a request to azure/gcp translation api
makeTranslationRequest(originalText)
```

I've looked into this `length` keyword and [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) says that `length` counts UTF-16 code units, which doesn't much make sense to me.

Are code points and UTF-16 code units the same thing?

If not, how can I possibly count the number of code points in one text in Javascript (node.js)?

Comment: Unicode code points and UTF code units (whether that be UTF-7, UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32), are not the same thing (though, in UTF-32, they can be treated the same).  See [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) for what UTF-16 is and how its 16bit code units relate to Unicode code points.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are different. I know, MDN uses the rarely used "code units" term, which confuses people a lot.

Code points are the number given to a Unicode element (*character*). This is independent to the encoding, and it can be as high as 0x​10FFFF. UTF-32 code units are equivalent to Unicode code points (if you are using the correct endianess).

Code units in UTF-16 are units of 16bit data. Using 16bit data helps us to ignore the endianess (but when you are reading bytes, remember this extra difficulty). UTF-16 uses 1 or 2 code units to describe a code point, depending on its value.

Code points below (or equal) to 0xFFFF (the old limit/expectation of Unicode that such numbers were enough to encode all characters) use just 1 code unit, and its value is the same as the code point.

Unicode expanded the code point space, so now code points between 0x010000..0x10FFFF require 2 code units (and we use "surrogates" to encode such characters), 4 bytes total.

So, code points are not the same as code units. For UTF-16, code units are 16bit long, and code points could be 1 or 2 code units.

Note: character width, and number of graphemes (printed characters) is independent of codepoints: some characters have "double width", and many codepoints are combining characters, which modify the previous character (e.g. by adding an accent).

How to count code points?

I would iterate through every code unit, and count only code units which are outside the range 0xDC00..0xDFFF. This should be the correct number of code points (assuming a valid Unicode string, so always a pair of low and high surrogates).

Comment: Rather than analyzing the individual code units manually, I would use the string's [`codepointAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) method instead, and then skip past 1 or 2 chars based on the codepoint value. Let Javascript analyze the surrogates for you. Or better, use the string's [`iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator), which iterates code points, not code units.